# JavaScript error when using Classic ASP tags( <% %>) to generate a dynamic HTML

Tags: asp-classic

I'm new to the Classic Asp and java Script. please help me...!
I'm trying to generate a dynamic HTML upon button click using javascript. In that HTML I have one control for which i need to use classic asp to render it. When i use the asp tags(<% %> I'm getting a object expected error.

Javascript that generated dynamic HTML:

```
function InsertNewLine(nItemNum){
htmlString = htmlString + '<img alt="" src="../images/search-glass.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;margin:0px 22px 0px 22px"/>' ;
htmlString = htmlString + '<% Display.Select %>' ;}
```

Display.Select is a function writen in VB6 which dynamically generates a DropDownList.

Error: Object Expected

Comment: What exactly is Display select

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of display.select is it a string or does it `response.write`?

Try:

```
function InsertNewLine(nItemNum){
htmlString = htmlString + '<img alt="" src="../images/search-glass.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;margin:0px 22px 0px 22px"/>' ;
htmlString = htmlString + '<% =Display.Select %>' ;}
```

The difference being `<%= %>` which will add the output of `display.select` to the output buffer response.

**Update**

Check what is rendered to the page using `<% %>` and check the use of quotes for attributes in the vb output. YOu may need to swap your singel quote to double quotes or remove them all together so you may want:

```
htmlString = htmlString + "<% Display.Select %>"
```

or

```
htmlString = htmlString + <% Display.Select %>
```

depending on the output of `Display.Select`

Comment: The output is responce.write

Comment: Added equals sign and getting - "Expected ')' " but there is no open paranthesis

Comment: View the source as rendered to the web page, what do you see with `<% %>` and with `<%= %>` Also have you instantiated the `Display` object?

Comment: @fabolous - Have you tried putting `()`'s after the `Select`?  This is a method of `Display` by the look of it.  Failing that there could be a problem with the `Display` object or `Select` method.  Where does it come from?

Comment: Doesnt matter what I use either <% %> or <%= %> I'm able to see the html select and options which that function will give but when I use <% %> as I told you I'm getting the javascript error as Object expected. And when I use <%= %>

Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee'

Expected ')'

/ASPPAGES/example.asp, line 1479

Response.Write(Display.Select )
 
------------------------------^

Comment: Please update your question to include  what is rendered to the page for the `InsertNewLine` function when using `<% %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the equal sign

```
htmlString = htmlString + '<%= Display.Select %>';
```

> Display.Select is a function writen in VB6 which dynamically generates a DropDownList.

```
htmlString = htmlString + '<%= Display.Select() %>';
```

Comment: Added equals sign and getting - "Expected ')' " but there is no open paranthesis